# search data in tree structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

could you please recommend effective (fast) algorithm of searching data in tree structure like below:

```
struct Node
{
    std::string value;

    Node* parent;
    std::vector<Node*> childs;
}
```

the goal is to find all the Nodes where Node.value match the search pattern.
Thank you

Comment: Unless you provide us with more information about the search pattern or the structure of the tree, I believe that full scan (using DFS for example) is the only way to do so.

Comment: what you are looking for is a [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree):

Comment: You can insert nodes in a sorted (and perhaps balanced) manner so that it will be fast to search. It will however make the insert operation more complex.

Comment: let say I have 3 nodes in structure, having values = {'abc', 'def', 'xyz'}. My search pattern is 'e' that will match only the second node.

Comment: effecitive and fast like in "using the right `std` container(s) and algorithms" or fast&effective like in "spending lots of time to write your own optimized tree structure" ?

Comment: Can you change the structure of the tree? Or do you need to keep it as you posted, with what I assume to be a random insertion method?

Comment: you can be lazy and just implement in-order traversion and check each element or use a more sophisticated approach like a B-Tree

Comment: I cannot change the structure of the tree, it is fixed. Maybe there is a way to derive additional proxy structure that will be used in search in more efficient way and pointed out to original tree.

Comment: Since you cannot change the structure of the tree; the only method you have is to perform a full scan of the tree (using DFS), and continuously adding the nodes that match your searching pattern to a global vector.

Comment: @SaidA.Sryheni That is not correct. Inserting element in a "clever" way will allow a search to skip part of the tree.

Comment: full scan is definitely is not a solution

Comment: @4386427 Could you provide an example noting that the search pattern is completely random and unpredictable?

Comment: @4386427 "I cannot change the structure of the tree, it is fixed" rather implies OP is not the one doing the inserting

Comment: is there a way to introduce (derive from original) structure with kind of indexes that would allow more effective search?

Comment: @SaidA.Sryheni A standard binary search tree is the obvious example. It doesn't matter whether the tree holds numbers or strings

Comment: OK, I have one question: what does the tree have to do with all this?? say you inserted the elements as strings into an array for example, what difference would it make?!

Comment: @user478681 any such indexing by definition requires a full scan to populate

Comment: @user478681 Do you write the `insert node` method your self?

Comment: @4386427 Binary search tree is definitely a wrong answer. Did you see the example he provided? (let say I have 3 nodes in structure, having values = {'abc', 'def', 'xyz'}. My search pattern is 'e' that will match only the second node.) How would a binary search tree help you here? When you are currently visiting a node, you have absolutely no idea whether to move to the left or the right child !!

Comment: can you have `values = {"adx", "bey", "cfz", "def"}` (in any order)?

Comment: @SaidA.Sryheni " When you are currently visiting a node, you have absolutely no idea whether to move to the left or the right child " Sorry but you are wrong. You can test strings for `<`, `==` and `>` just like numbers. Since more than two childs is allowed here, OP can even implement some thing more sophisticated

Comment: any order. as I mentioned, it is tree where every node can have a unique value, not sorted. It doesn't matter how Node is inserted. Original structure cannot be changed. I can only imagine additional derived structure that will have reference to original nodes and maybe organized in some effective for search way

Comment: You also don't have a binary tree. Each node has an arbitrary number of children. If you can define a [strict weak ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) on the data + children, you could sort the children and only look at the range returned by `std::equal_range` over that order

Comment: @4386427 That's not the point !! What would you get if you tested strings? say one string is smaller than the other, what would that give you? Does this mean that one of them contains an 'e' while the other doesn't?! Check his example, his search pattern can be a substring from inside the string, with characters before and after it !! Comparing strings will test strings starting from the beginning. Do you get my point now?

Comment: But we still don't know if your data is restricted to cases where such an ordering exists

Comment: @user478681 also `values = {'abc', 'def', 'xyz'}` is not a tree, it is a sequence. `values = {{'abc', { 'pqr', 'mno' }}, {'def', {}}, {'xyz', { 'asd', 'fgh', 'hjk'}}}` is a tree

Comment: it is just an example, you can put it in hierarchy, the point is that every node can have any string value

Comment: Then there *isn't* anything better than a full scan

Answer (score 2):

A simple preorder traversal:

```
void match(Node * node, const std::string & value, std::vector<Node*> & result)
{
    if (node->value == value)
    {
        result.push_back(node);
    }
    for (Node * child : node->childs)
    {
        match(child, value, result);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node * root = /* ... */
    std::string value = /* ... */;
    std::vector<Node*> matches;
    match(root, value, matches);
}
```

Which generalises to

```
template<typename Action>
void preorder(Node * node, Action action)
{
    action(node);
    for (Node * child : node->childs)
    {
        preorder(child, action);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node * root = /* ... */
    std::string value = /* ... */;
    std::vector<Node*> matches;
    preorder(root, [&](Node * node){ if (node->value == value) { matches->push_back(node); } });
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it is full scan traverse. For my particular task where data structure is huge it is not optimal...

Comment: As `Node` doesn't maintain any invariant, you can't do better. If you can add some invariants to the population of `Node` then you might be able to do better

Comment: @user478681 it might be slow, but that doesn't mean that it isn't optimal.